# updating classes with dropdown select value with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, html-select

I have a div with some optional set of classes which i want to switch using dropdown select. With best of my knowledge I have written the following script which is not working perfectly .. it throws an "undefined" value if select value is null. It will be very kind of you to solve this problem or can guide me to some better technique with jQuery to achieve my goal

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var ContainerClasses;
  var TxtColor;
  var BackGroundColor;

  // SWITCHING TEXT COLOR
  $("#TxtColor").change(function() {
    if ($(this).val()) {
      TxtColor = ' ' + $(this).val();
    } else {
      TxtColor = "";
    }
    upDateTheme();
  });

  // SWITCHING BACKGROUND COLOR 
  $("#BackGroundColor").change(function() {
    if ($(this).val()) {
      BackGroundColor = ' ' + $(this).val();
    } else {
      BackGroundColor = "";
    }
    upDateTheme();
  });

  function upDateTheme() {
    ContainerClasses = TxtColor + ' ' + BackGroundColor;
    $('#Main').addClass(ContainerClasses);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Main" class="">
  <!-- SOME HTML INSIDE -->
</div>
<div class="optionBox">
  <label>Text Color</label>
  <select id="TxtColor">
    <option value="">None</option>
    <option value="ClassA">Class A</option>
    <option value="ClassB">Class A</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="optionBox">
  <label>BackGround Color</label>
  <select id="BackGroundColor">
    <option value="">None</option>
    <option value="Class1">Class 1</option>
    <option value="Class2">Class 2</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: hi try out solution and let me know

Comment: "Background" is one word, LOL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very simple. Your values are `undefined`. So Define the empty values initially like below.

```
 var ContainerClasses="";
 var TxtColor="";
 var BackGroundColor="";
```

I have added some css styles and created the fiddle. Check the [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/avfnxr2y/1/)

The Logic part is before updating the theme you have to clear the old classes. Otherwise it will added in the div like `div class="classA class1 classB class2....."`. So I have remove the classes and then update the new classes in the snippet below.

```js
var ContainerClasses="";
var TxtColor="";
var BackGroundColor = "";

// SWITCHING TEXT COLOR
$( "#TxtColor" ).change(function() {
    if ($(this).val()) {
        TxtColor= ' ' + $(this).val();
    } else { TxtColor = ""; }
    upDateTheme();
});

// SWITCHING BACKGROUND COLOR   
$( "#BackGroundColor" ).change(function() {
    if ($(this).val()) {
        BackGroundColor= ' ' + $(this).val();
    } else { BackGroundColor = ""; }
    upDateTheme();
});

function upDateTheme() {
    $('#Main').removeClass();
    ContainerClasses= TxtColor + ' ' + BackGroundColor;
    $('#Main').addClass(ContainerClasses);
}
```

```css
div.ClassA {
  font-size:40px;
  color:green;
}
div.ClassB {
  font-size:10px;
  color:red;
}
div.Class1 {
  background:red;
}
div.Class2 {
  background:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Main" class="">
 Test
</div>
 <div class="optionBox">
    <label>Text Color</label>
    <select id="TxtColor">
        <option value="">None</option>
        <option value="ClassA">Class A</option>
        <option value="ClassB">Class B</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="optionBox">
    <label>BackGround Color</label>
    <select id="BackGroundColor">
        <option value="">None</option>
        <option value="Class1">Class 1</option>
        <option value="Class2">Class 2</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Friend if u inspect the #Main div the script just keeps on adding the values instead of replacing them ... and it also stops working after few random selects

Comment: I have updated my answer bro. Read my answer again and look at the snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Your code in cleaner simpler form. You don't need global variables. Use parameters which you can pass in the functions. That's what they are for:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $( "#TxtColor, #BackGroundColor" ).change(function() {
      upDateTheme(
          $(this).attr('id'),
          $(this).val()
      );
  });

  function upDateTheme(id, value) {
    var $main = $('#Main');
    // via the id find all options to reset
    // remove all those classes before adding the new one
    $('#'+id+' option').each(function(index, element){
        $main.removeClass(element.value);
    });
    
    $main.addClass(value);
  }
});
```

```css
#Main {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: solid 1px black;
}

#Main.ClassA {
    color: red;
}
#Main.ClassB {
    color: green;
}
#Main.Class1 {
    background-color: orange;
}
#Main.Class2 {
    background-color: fuchsia;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Main" class="">
  Lorem ipsum
</div>
<div class="optionBox">
  <label>Text Color</label>
  <select id="TxtColor">
    <option value="">None</option>
    <option value="ClassA">Class A</option>
    <option value="ClassB">Class B</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="optionBox">
  <label>BackGround Color</label>
  <select id="BackGroundColor">
    <option value="">None</option>
    <option value="Class1">Class 1</option>
    <option value="Class2">Class 2</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

To make it a good piece of code you should consider using `data-attributes`  and use the colors as values, but just to give you an idea how it could be done with `data-attributes` see this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $( "#TxtColor, #BackGroundColor" ).change(function() {
      upDateTheme(
          $(this).attr('id'),
          $(this).val()
      );
  });

  function upDateTheme(parameter, value) {
      $('#Main').attr('data-' + parameter, value);
  }
});
```

```css
#Main {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: solid 1px black;
}

[data-txtcolor="ClassA"] {
    color: red;
}
[data-txtcolor="ClassB"] {
    color: green;
}
[data-backgroundcolor="Class1"] {
    background-color: orange;
}
[data-backgroundcolor="Class2"] {
    background-color: fuchsia;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Main" class="">
 <!-- SOME HTML INSIDE -->
 lorem ipsum
</div>
 <div class="optionBox">
    <label>Text Color</label>
    <select id="TxtColor">
        <option value="">None</option>
        <option value="ClassA">Class A</option>
        <option value="ClassB">Class B</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="optionBox">
    <label>BackGround Color</label>
    <select id="BackGroundColor">
        <option value="">None</option>
        <option value="Class1">Class 1</option>
        <option value="Class2">Class 2</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

For simplicity I recommend to always use lower case letters only in HTML for tags, classes and parameters. Be careful with this code and problems could occur see how it changes the `id` to lower case which will be used later in CSS!

Comment: this is the smartest way to do this but I am calling different css classes so I dont know how will i do that with Data attribute.

Comment: @kamranshah updated the answer to show how you could also write less/simpler code with classes.

Answer (score 0):

If you initialize your three variables it should work fine.

Also, if you want to make the code a bit smaller, you don't really need the if statements. Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ozmemroy/12/) as an example.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var ContainerClasses = "";
  var TxtColor = "";
  var BackGroundColor = "";

  // SWITCHING TEXT COLOR
  $("#TxtColor").change(function() {
    TxtColor = ' ' + $(this).val();
    upDateTheme();
  });

  // SWITCHING BACKGROUND COLOR   
  $("#BackGroundColor").change(function() {
    BackGroundColor = ' ' + $(this).val();
    upDateTheme();
  });

  function upDateTheme() {
    ContainerClasses = TxtColor + ' ' + BackGroundColor;
    $('#Main').addClass(ContainerClasses);
    console.log(ContainerClasses);
  }
});
```